# Vertically print in curly brackets {,}

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, function

I need it to print with “country_name” and “capital_city” with Curly Brackets vertically:

```
def json_countries_and_capitals():
    """
    This function prints each country and its capital in json format.
    """
output = [{'country_name': i[0], 'capital_city':i[1]} for i in countries_and_capitals]
```

I tried this but it doesn't print out with curly brackets but it does print out how I need it to.

```
countries_plus_capitals = json.dumps(countries_and_capitals, indent=4)
while countries_plus_capitals:
    print(output)
    print(countries_plus_capitals)
    break
```

```
It prints this horizontally:
```

[{'country_name': 'Afghanistan', 'capital_city': 'Kabul'},ect...

```
I need it to print like this vertically:
```

[
{
“country_name” : “Afghanistan”,
“capital_city” : “Kabul”
},
{
“country_name” : “Albania”,
“capital_city” : “Tirana (Tirane)”
},
{
“country_name” : “Algeria”,
“capital_city” : “Algiers”
},
… etc …
{
“country_name” : “Zimbabwe”,
“capital_city” : “Harare”
}
]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has not shown any attempt at solving the problem which is easily solved with a basic understanding of python data types.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the list and create the dictionary.

```py
l = [ [ "Afghanistan", "Kabul" ], [ "Albania", "Tirana (Tirane)" ], [ "Algeria", "Algiers" ], [ "Andorra", "Andorra la Vella" ], [ "Angola", "Luanda" ], [ "Antigua and Barbuda", "Saint John's" ], [ "Argentina", "Buenos Aires" ], [ "Armenia", "Yerevan" ], [ "Australia", "Canberra" ], [ "Austria", "Vienna" ], [ "Azerbaijan", "Baku" ], [ "Bahamas", "Nassau" ], [ "Bahrain", "Manama" ], [ "Bangladesh", "Dhaka" ], [ "Barbados", "Bridgetown" ], [ "Belarus", "Minsk" ], [ "Belgium", "Brussels" ], [ "Belize", "Belmopan" ], [ "Benin", "Porto Novo" ], [ "Bhutan", "Thimphu" ], [ "Bolivia", "Sucre" ], [ "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Sarajevo" ], [ "Botswana", "Gaborone" ], [ "Brazil", "Brasilia" ], [ "Brunei", "Bandar Seri Begawan" ], [ "Bulgaria", "Sofia" ], [ "Burkina Faso", "Ouagadougou" ], [ "Burundi", "Gitega" ], [ "Cambodia", "Phnom Penh" ], [ "Cameroon", "Yaounde" ], [ "Canada", "Ottawa" ], [ "Cape Verde", "Praia" ], [ "Central African Republic", "Bangui" ], [ "Chad", "N'Djamena" ], [ "Chile", "Santiago" ], [ "China", "Beijing" ], [ "Colombia", "Bogota" ], [ "Comoros", "Moroni" ], [ "Congo, Democratic Republic of the", "Kinshasa" ], [ "Congo, Republic of the", "Brazzaville" ], [ "Costa Rica", "San Jose" ], [ "Cote d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)", "Yamoussoukro" ], [ "Croatia", "Zagreb" ], [ "Cuba", "Havana" ], [ "Cyprus", "Nicosia" ], [ "Czech Republic (Czechia)", "Prague" ], [ "Denmark", "Copenhagen" ], [ "Djibouti", "Djibouti" ], [ "Dominica", "Roseau" ], [ "Dominican Republic", "Santo Domingo" ], [ "East Timor", "Dili" ], [ "Ecuador", "Quito" ], [ "Egypt", "Cairo" ], [ "El Salvador", "San Salvador" ], [ "England", "London" ], [ "Equatorial Guinea", "Malabo" ], [ "Eritrea", "Asmara" ], [ "Estonia", "Tallinn" ], [ "Eswatini (Swaziland)", "Mbabana" ], [ "Ethiopia", "Addis Ababa" ], [ "Federated States of Micronesia", "Palikir" ], [ "Fiji", "Suva" ], [ "Finland", "Helsinki" ], [ "France", "Paris" ], [ "Gabon", "Libreville" ], [ "Gambia", "Banjul" ], [ "Georgia", "Tbilisi" ], [ "Germany", "Berlin" ], [ "Ghana", "Accra" ], [ "Greece", "Athens" ], [ "Grenada", "Saint George's" ], [ "Guatemala", "Guatemala City" ], [ "Guinea", "Conakry" ], [ "Guinea-Bissau", "Bissau" ], [ "Guyana", "Georgetown" ], [ "Haiti", "Port au Prince" ], [ "Honduras", "Tegucigalpa" ], [ "Hungary", "Budapest" ], [ "Iceland", "Reykjavik" ], [ "India", "New Delhi" ], [ "Indonesia", "Jakarta" ], [ "Iran", "Tehran" ], [ "Iraq", "Baghdad" ], [ "Ireland", "Dublin" ], [ "Israel", "Jerusalem" ], [ "Italy", "Rome" ], [ "Jamaica", "Kingston" ], [ "Japan", "Tokyo" ], [ "Jordan", "Amman" ], [ "Kazakhstan", "Nur-Sultan" ], [ "Kenya", "Nairobi" ], [ "Kiribati", "Tarawa Atoll" ], [ "Kosovo", "Pristina" ], [ "Kuwait", "Kuwait City" ], [ "Kyrgyzstan", "Bishkek" ], [ "Laos", "Vientiane" ], [ "Latvia", "Riga" ], [ "Lebanon", "Beirut" ], [ "Lesotho", "Maseru" ], [ "Liberia", "Monrovia" ], [ "Libya", "Tripoli" ], [ "Liechtenstein", "Vaduz" ], [ "Lithuania", "Vilnius" ], [ "Luxembourg", "Luxembourg" ], [ "Madagascar", "Antananarivo" ], [ "Malawi", "Lilongwe" ], [ "Malaysia", "Kuala Lumpur" ], [ "Maldives", "Male" ], [ "Mali", "Bamako" ], [ "Malta", "Valletta" ], [ "Marshall Islands", "Majuro" ], [ "Mauritania", "Nouakchott" ], [ "Mauritius", "Port Louis" ], [ "Mexico", "Mexico City" ], [ "Moldova", "Chisinau" ], [ "Monaco", "Monaco" ], [ "Mongolia", "Ulaanbaatar" ], [ "Montenegro", "Podgorica" ], [ "Morocco", "Rabat" ], [ "Mozambique", "Maputo" ], [ "Myanmar (Burma)", "Nay Pyi Taw" ], [ "Namibia", "Windhoek" ], [ "Nauru", "No official capital" ], [ "Nepal", "Kathmandu" ], [ "Netherlands", "Amsterdam" ], [ "New Zealand", "Wellington" ], [ "Nicaragua", "Managua" ], [ "Niger", "Niamey" ], [ "Nigeria", "Abuja" ], [ "North Korea", "Pyongyang" ], [ "North Macedonia (Macedonia)", "Skopje" ], [ "Northern Ireland", "Belfast" ], [ "Norway", "Oslo" ], [ "Oman", "Muscat" ], [ "Pakistan", "Islamabad" ], [ "Palau", "Melekeok" ], [ "Panama", "Panama City" ], [ "Papua New Guinea", "Port Moresby" ], [ "Paraguay", "Asuncion" ], [ "Peru", "Lima" ], [ "Philippines", "Manila" ], [ "Poland", "Warsaw" ], [ "Portugal", "Lisbon" ], [ "Qatar", "Doha" ], [ "Romania", "Bucharest" ], [ "Russia", "Moscow" ], [ "Rwanda", "Kigali" ], [ "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Basseterre" ], [ "Saint Lucia", "Castries" ], [ "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Kingstown" ], [ "Samoa", "Apia" ], [ "San Marino", "San Marino" ], [ "Sao Tome and Principe", "Sao Tome" ], [ "Saudi Arabia", "Riyadh" ], [ "Scotland", "Edinburgh" ], [ "Senegal", "Dakar" ], [ "Serbia", "Belgrade" ], [ "Seychelles", "Victoria" ], [ "Sierra Leone", "Freetown" ], [ "Singapore", "Singapore" ], [ "Slovakia", "Bratislava" ], [ "Slovenia", "Ljubljana" ], [ "Solomon Islands", "Honiara" ], [ "Somalia", "Mogadishu" ], [ "South Africa", "Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town" ], [ "South Korea", "Seoul" ], [ "South Sudan", "Juba" ], [ "Spain", "Madrid" ], [ "Sri Lanka", "Colombo" ], [ "Sudan", "Khartoum" ], [ "Suriname", "Paramaribo" ], [ "Sweden", "Stockholm" ], [ "Switzerland", "Bern" ], [ "Syria", "Damascus" ], [ "Taiwan", "Taipei" ], [ "Tajikistan", "Dushanbe" ], [ "Tanzania", "Dodoma" ], [ "Thailand", "Bangkok" ], [ "Togo", "Lome" ], [ "Tonga", "Nuku'alofa" ], [ "Trinidad and Tobago", "Port of Spain" ], [ "Tunisia", "Tunis" ], [ "Turkey", "Ankara" ], [ "Turkmenistan", "Ashgabat" ], [ "Tuvalu", "Funafuti" ], [ "Uganda", "Kampala" ], [ "Ukraine", "Kiev" ], [ "United Arab Emirates", "Abu Dhabi" ], [ "United Kingdom", "London" ], [ "United States", "Washington D.C." ], [ "Uruguay", "Montevideo" ], [ "Uzbekistan", "Tashkent" ], [ "Vanuatu", "Port Vila" ], [ "Vatican City", "Vatican City" ], [ "Venezuela", "Caracas" ], [ "Vietnam", "Hanoi" ], [ "Wales", "Cardiff" ], [ "Yemen", "Sana'a" ], [ "Zambia", "Lusaka" ], [ "Zimbabwe", "Harare" ] ]



output = [{'country_name': i[0], 'capital_city':i[1]} for i in l]
```

```
[{'country_name': 'Afghanistan', 'capital_city': 'Kabul'},
 {'country_name': 'Albania', 'capital_city': 'Tirana (Tirane)'},
 {'country_name': 'Algeria', 'capital_city': 'Algiers'},
 {'country_name': 'Andorra', 'capital_city': 'Andorra la Vella'},
 {'country_name': 'Angola', 'capital_city': 'Luanda'},
 {'country_name': 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'capital_city': "Saint John's"},
 {'country_name': 'Argentina', 'capital_city': 'Buenos Aires'},
 {'country_name': 'Armenia', 'capital_city': 'Yerevan'},
 {'country_name': 'Australia', 'capital_city': 'Canberra'},
 {'country_name': 'Austria', 'capital_city': 'Vienna'},
 {'country_name': 'Azerbaijan', 'capital_city': 'Baku'},
 {'country_name': 'Bahamas', 'capital_city': 'Nassau'},
 {'country_name': 'Bahrain', 'capital_city': 'Manama'},
 {'country_name': 'Bangladesh', 'capital_city': 'Dhaka'},
 {'country_name': 'Barbados', 'capital_city': 'Bridgetown'},
 {'country_name': 'Belarus', 'capital_city': 'Minsk'},
 {'country_name': 'Belgium', 'capital_city': 'Brussels'},
 {'country_name': 'Belize', 'capital_city': 'Belmopan'},
 {'country_name': 'Benin', 'capital_city': 'Porto Novo'},
 {'country_name': 'Bhutan', 'capital_city': 'Thimphu'},
 {'country_name': 'Bolivia', 'capital_city': 'Sucre'},
 {'country_name': 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', 'capital_city': 'Sarajevo'},
 {'country_name': 'Botswana', 'capital_city': 'Gaborone'},
 {'country_name': 'Brazil', 'capital_city': 'Brasilia'},
 {'country_name': 'Brunei', 'capital_city': 'Bandar Seri Begawan'},
 {'country_name': 'Bulgaria', 'capital_city': 'Sofia'},
 {'country_name': 'Burkina Faso', 'capital_city': 'Ouagadougou'},
 {'country_name': 'Burundi', 'capital_city': 'Gitega'},
 {'country_name': 'Cambodia', 'capital_city': 'Phnom Penh'},
 {'country_name': 'Cameroon', 'capital_city': 'Yaounde'},
 {'country_name': 'Canada', 'capital_city': 'Ottawa'},
 {'country_name': 'Cape Verde', 'capital_city': 'Praia'},
 {'country_name': 'Central African Republic', 'capital_city': 'Bangui'},
 {'country_name': 'Chad', 'capital_city': "N'Djamena"},
 {'country_name': 'Chile', 'capital_city': 'Santiago'},
 {'country_name': 'China', 'capital_city': 'Beijing'},
 {'country_name': 'Colombia', 'capital_city': 'Bogota'},
 {'country_name': 'Comoros', 'capital_city': 'Moroni'},
 {'country_name': 'Congo, Democratic Republic of the',
  'capital_city': 'Kinshasa'},
 {'country_name': 'Congo, Republic of the', 'capital_city': 'Brazzaville'},
 {'country_name': 'Costa Rica', 'capital_city': 'San Jose'},
 {'country_name': "Cote d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)",
  'capital_city': 'Yamoussoukro'},
 {'country_name': 'Croatia', 'capital_city': 'Zagreb'},
 {'country_name': 'Cuba', 'capital_city': 'Havana'},
 {'country_name': 'Cyprus', 'capital_city': 'Nicosia'},
 {'country_name': 'Czech Republic (Czechia)', 'capital_city': 'Prague'},
 {'country_name': 'Denmark', 'capital_city': 'Copenhagen'},
 {'country_name': 'Djibouti', 'capital_city': 'Djibouti'},
 {'country_name': 'Dominica', 'capital_city': 'Roseau'},
 {'country_name': 'Dominican Republic', 'capital_city': 'Santo Domingo'},
 {'country_name': 'East Timor', 'capital_city': 'Dili'},
 {'country_name': 'Ecuador', 'capital_city': 'Quito'},
 {'country_name': 'Egypt', 'capital_city': 'Cairo'},
 {'country_name': 'El Salvador', 'capital_city': 'San Salvador'},
 {'country_name': 'England', 'capital_city': 'London'},
 {'country_name': 'Equatorial Guinea', 'capital_city': 'Malabo'},
 {'country_name': 'Eritrea', 'capital_city': 'Asmara'},
 {'country_name': 'Estonia', 'capital_city': 'Tallinn'},
 {'country_name': 'Eswatini (Swaziland)', 'capital_city': 'Mbabana'},
 {'country_name': 'Ethiopia', 'capital_city': 'Addis Ababa'},
 {'country_name': 'Federated States of Micronesia', 'capital_city': 'Palikir'},
 {'country_name': 'Fiji', 'capital_city': 'Suva'},
 {'country_name': 'Finland', 'capital_city': 'Helsinki'},
 {'country_name': 'France', 'capital_city': 'Paris'},
 {'country_name': 'Gabon', 'capital_city': 'Libreville'},
 {'country_name': 'Gambia', 'capital_city': 'Banjul'},
 {'country_name': 'Georgia', 'capital_city': 'Tbilisi'},
 {'country_name': 'Germany', 'capital_city': 'Berlin'},
 {'country_name': 'Ghana', 'capital_city': 'Accra'},
 {'country_name': 'Greece', 'capital_city': 'Athens'},
 {'country_name': 'Grenada', 'capital_city': "Saint George's"},
 {'country_name': 'Guatemala', 'capital_city': 'Guatemala City'},
 {'country_name': 'Guinea', 'capital_city': 'Conakry'},
 {'country_name': 'Guinea-Bissau', 'capital_city': 'Bissau'},
 {'country_name': 'Guyana', 'capital_city': 'Georgetown'},
 {'country_name': 'Haiti', 'capital_city': 'Port au Prince'},
 {'country_name': 'Honduras', 'capital_city': 'Tegucigalpa'},
 {'country_name': 'Hungary', 'capital_city': 'Budapest'},
 {'country_name': 'Iceland', 'capital_city': 'Reykjavik'},
 {'country_name': 'India', 'capital_city': 'New Delhi'},
 {'country_name': 'Indonesia', 'capital_city': 'Jakarta'},
 {'country_name': 'Iran', 'capital_city': 'Tehran'},
 {'country_name': 'Iraq', 'capital_city': 'Baghdad'},
 {'country_name': 'Ireland', 'capital_city': 'Dublin'},
 {'country_name': 'Israel', 'capital_city': 'Jerusalem'},
 {'country_name': 'Italy', 'capital_city': 'Rome'},
 {'country_name': 'Jamaica', 'capital_city': 'Kingston'},
 {'country_name': 'Japan', 'capital_city': 'Tokyo'},
 {'country_name': 'Jordan', 'capital_city': 'Amman'},
 {'country_name': 'Kazakhstan', 'capital_city': 'Nur-Sultan'},
 {'country_name': 'Kenya', 'capital_city': 'Nairobi'},
 {'country_name': 'Kiribati', 'capital_city': 'Tarawa Atoll'},
 {'country_name': 'Kosovo', 'capital_city': 'Pristina'},
 {'country_name': 'Kuwait', 'capital_city': 'Kuwait City'},
 {'country_name': 'Kyrgyzstan', 'capital_city': 'Bishkek'},
 {'country_name': 'Laos', 'capital_city': 'Vientiane'},
 {'country_name': 'Latvia', 'capital_city': 'Riga'},
 {'country_name': 'Lebanon', 'capital_city': 'Beirut'},
 {'country_name': 'Lesotho', 'capital_city': 'Maseru'},
 {'country_name': 'Liberia', 'capital_city': 'Monrovia'},
 {'country_name': 'Libya', 'capital_city': 'Tripoli'},
 {'country_name': 'Liechtenstein', 'capital_city': 'Vaduz'},
 {'country_name': 'Lithuania', 'capital_city': 'Vilnius'},
 {'country_name': 'Luxembourg', 'capital_city': 'Luxembourg'},
 {'country_name': 'Madagascar', 'capital_city': 'Antananarivo'},
 {'country_name': 'Malawi', 'capital_city': 'Lilongwe'},
 {'country_name': 'Malaysia', 'capital_city': 'Kuala Lumpur'},
 {'country_name': 'Maldives', 'capital_city': 'Male'},
 {'country_name': 'Mali', 'capital_city': 'Bamako'},
 {'country_name': 'Malta', 'capital_city': 'Valletta'},
 {'country_name': 'Marshall Islands', 'capital_city': 'Majuro'},
 {'country_name': 'Mauritania', 'capital_city': 'Nouakchott'},
 {'country_name': 'Mauritius', 'capital_city': 'Port Louis'},
 {'country_name': 'Mexico', 'capital_city': 'Mexico City'},
 {'country_name': 'Moldova', 'capital_city': 'Chisinau'},
 {'country_name': 'Monaco', 'capital_city': 'Monaco'},
 {'country_name': 'Mongolia', 'capital_city': 'Ulaanbaatar'},
 {'country_name': 'Montenegro', 'capital_city': 'Podgorica'},
 {'country_name': 'Morocco', 'capital_city': 'Rabat'},
 {'country_name': 'Mozambique', 'capital_city': 'Maputo'},
 {'country_name': 'Myanmar (Burma)', 'capital_city': 'Nay Pyi Taw'},
 {'country_name': 'Namibia', 'capital_city': 'Windhoek'},
 {'country_name': 'Nauru', 'capital_city': 'No official capital'},
 {'country_name': 'Nepal', 'capital_city': 'Kathmandu'},
 {'country_name': 'Netherlands', 'capital_city': 'Amsterdam'},
 {'country_name': 'New Zealand', 'capital_city': 'Wellington'},
 {'country_name': 'Nicaragua', 'capital_city': 'Managua'},
 {'country_name': 'Niger', 'capital_city': 'Niamey'},
 {'country_name': 'Nigeria', 'capital_city': 'Abuja'},
 {'country_name': 'North Korea', 'capital_city': 'Pyongyang'},
 {'country_name': 'North Macedonia (Macedonia)', 'capital_city': 'Skopje'},
 {'country_name': 'Northern Ireland', 'capital_city': 'Belfast'},
 {'country_name': 'Norway', 'capital_city': 'Oslo'},
 {'country_name': 'Oman', 'capital_city': 'Muscat'},
 {'country_name': 'Pakistan', 'capital_city': 'Islamabad'},
 {'country_name': 'Palau', 'capital_city': 'Melekeok'},
 {'country_name': 'Panama', 'capital_city': 'Panama City'},
 {'country_name': 'Papua New Guinea', 'capital_city': 'Port Moresby'},
 {'country_name': 'Paraguay', 'capital_city': 'Asuncion'},
 {'country_name': 'Peru', 'capital_city': 'Lima'},
 {'country_name': 'Philippines', 'capital_city': 'Manila'},
 {'country_name': 'Poland', 'capital_city': 'Warsaw'},
 {'country_name': 'Portugal', 'capital_city': 'Lisbon'},
 {'country_name': 'Qatar', 'capital_city': 'Doha'},
 {'country_name': 'Romania', 'capital_city': 'Bucharest'},
 {'country_name': 'Russia', 'capital_city': 'Moscow'},
 {'country_name': 'Rwanda', 'capital_city': 'Kigali'},
 {'country_name': 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'capital_city': 'Basseterre'},
 {'country_name': 'Saint Lucia', 'capital_city': 'Castries'},
 {'country_name': 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
  'capital_city': 'Kingstown'},
 {'country_name': 'Samoa', 'capital_city': 'Apia'},
 {'country_name': 'San Marino', 'capital_city': 'San Marino'},
 {'country_name': 'Sao Tome and Principe', 'capital_city': 'Sao Tome'},
 {'country_name': 'Saudi Arabia', 'capital_city': 'Riyadh'},
 {'country_name': 'Scotland', 'capital_city': 'Edinburgh'},
 {'country_name': 'Senegal', 'capital_city': 'Dakar'},
 {'country_name': 'Serbia', 'capital_city': 'Belgrade'},
 {'country_name': 'Seychelles', 'capital_city': 'Victoria'},
 {'country_name': 'Sierra Leone', 'capital_city': 'Freetown'},
 {'country_name': 'Singapore', 'capital_city': 'Singapore'},
 {'country_name': 'Slovakia', 'capital_city': 'Bratislava'},
 {'country_name': 'Slovenia', 'capital_city': 'Ljubljana'},
 {'country_name': 'Solomon Islands', 'capital_city': 'Honiara'},
 {'country_name': 'Somalia', 'capital_city': 'Mogadishu'},
 {'country_name': 'South Africa',
  'capital_city': 'Pretoria, Bloemfontein, Cape Town'},
 {'country_name': 'South Korea', 'capital_city': 'Seoul'},
 {'country_name': 'South Sudan', 'capital_city': 'Juba'},
 {'country_name': 'Spain', 'capital_city': 'Madrid'},
 {'country_name': 'Sri Lanka', 'capital_city': 'Colombo'},
 {'country_name': 'Sudan', 'capital_city': 'Khartoum'},
 {'country_name': 'Suriname', 'capital_city': 'Paramaribo'},
 {'country_name': 'Sweden', 'capital_city': 'Stockholm'},
 {'country_name': 'Switzerland', 'capital_city': 'Bern'},
 {'country_name': 'Syria', 'capital_city': 'Damascus'},
 {'country_name': 'Taiwan', 'capital_city': 'Taipei'},
 {'country_name': 'Tajikistan', 'capital_city': 'Dushanbe'},
 {'country_name': 'Tanzania', 'capital_city': 'Dodoma'},
 {'country_name': 'Thailand', 'capital_city': 'Bangkok'},
 {'country_name': 'Togo', 'capital_city': 'Lome'},
 {'country_name': 'Tonga', 'capital_city': "Nuku'alofa"},
 {'country_name': 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'capital_city': 'Port of Spain'},
 {'country_name': 'Tunisia', 'capital_city': 'Tunis'},
 {'country_name': 'Turkey', 'capital_city': 'Ankara'},
 {'country_name': 'Turkmenistan', 'capital_city': 'Ashgabat'},
 {'country_name': 'Tuvalu', 'capital_city': 'Funafuti'},
 {'country_name': 'Uganda', 'capital_city': 'Kampala'},
 {'country_name': 'Ukraine', 'capital_city': 'Kiev'},
 {'country_name': 'United Arab Emirates', 'capital_city': 'Abu Dhabi'},
 {'country_name': 'United Kingdom', 'capital_city': 'London'},
 {'country_name': 'United States', 'capital_city': 'Washington D.C.'},
 {'country_name': 'Uruguay', 'capital_city': 'Montevideo'},
 {'country_name': 'Uzbekistan', 'capital_city': 'Tashkent'},
 {'country_name': 'Vanuatu', 'capital_city': 'Port Vila'},
 {'country_name': 'Vatican City', 'capital_city': 'Vatican City'},
 {'country_name': 'Venezuela', 'capital_city': 'Caracas'},
 {'country_name': 'Vietnam', 'capital_city': 'Hanoi'},
 {'country_name': 'Wales', 'capital_city': 'Cardiff'},
 {'country_name': 'Yemen', 'capital_city': "Sana'a"},
 {'country_name': 'Zambia', 'capital_city': 'Lusaka'},
 {'country_name': 'Zimbabwe', 'capital_city': 'Harare'}]
```

Comment: Thanks. When I printed it out I need it to go verticaly like this                                                                           [
 {
  “country_name” : “Afghanistan”,
  “capital_city” : “Kabul”
},
{
how can i do this?

Comment: Sorry, pardon me, didn't get you @Riel

Answer (score 0):

def json_countries_and_capitals():
"""
This function prints each country and its capital in json format.
"""

```
output = [{'country_name': i[0], 'capital_city':i[1]} for i in countries_and_capitals]
countries_plus_capitals = json.dumps(output, indent=4)
while countries_plus_capitals:
    print(countries_plus_capitals)
    break
```